# extjs grid incrementing element number slower popup windows

Tags: performance, extjs, grid, popup, extjs4

I have a gridpanel with 19 colums. There is a toolbar on the top with a button. When I press the button I call ext.widget to show a popup (graph) window (there is no data required from the grid). I'm using extjs 4.1.1.

In IE 10 when I have:

- 19 rows in the grid it takes about 1.5sec to show the graph window
- 147 rows in the grid it takes about 6.2sec to show the graph window

In IE 8:

- 19 rows in the grid: 1.7sec
- 147 rows in the grid: 6.7sec

In Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m:

- 19 rows in the grid: 0.8sec
- 147 rows in the grid: 1.8sec

Why is matters how many elements I have in the grid while creating a poup window (too big dom size)? What can be the bottleneck? How can I make it faster?

There are other popup windows there and all window creation is slower when I have more elements in the grid.

thanks,
HyGy

Answer (score 0):

So finally we found some solution to this. Before showing the new popup window we hide the whole grid, and then showing the popup window. This is significantly increses the speed in IE8, IE10.